# Using radioButtons to change between photos and using progress bar, textView and seek bar to change the opacity of chosen photo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar, android-framelayout

I'm a student who learns this year now Android studio with java. I have learned last week about the progress bar, seek bar, and radio buttons. My homework is to use radio buttons to change between photos and using a progress bar, textView (for the percentage), and seek bar to change the opacity of the chosen photo.

I tried as I could, and actually, when I look at "design", I can see my progress bar, Seek bar, and Text View, and all is good, but when I start the app (on SDK 19), the radio buttons don't change the chosen photo, and I even can't see the seek bar, progress bar, and text view.

Here is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/appbackground">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="353dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/element"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="135sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="195sp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
        android:elevation="2sp"/>


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/w"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Water"
            android:textColor="#03A9F4" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Earth"
            android:textColor="#652F00" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/f"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Fire"
            android:textColor="#FF5722" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Air"
            android:textColor="#9C9C9C" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="50%"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="570sp"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prog"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="625sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="650sp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:thumb="@drawable/uncleiroh2" />


</FrameLayout>
```

and here is the java:

```java
package com.example.avatarphotos;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private ImageView Element;
    private TextView textView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
   private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    //private RadioButton air;
    //private RadioButton earth;
    //private RadioButton water;
    //private RadioButton fire;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Element = findViewById(R.id.element);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.text);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.prog);
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seek);
        radioGroup=findViewById(R.id.radioG);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        progressBar.setProgress(i);
        textView.setText(""+i+"%");
        Element.setImageAlpha((int)(i/100.0*255));
    }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }



    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                Element.setImageResource(R.drawable.water);
                break;
            case 1:
                Element.setImageResource(R.drawable.earth);
                break;
            case 2:
                Element.setImageResource(R.drawable.fire);
                break;
            case 3:
                Element.setImageResource(R.drawable.air);
                break;
        }
    }

      }
```

design photo:
[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC62p.png)
app:
[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGMpy.png)
and well while writing this I got this error message so I don't know if it is really related:
[problem message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Ts4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try updating to a newer ADB version of ADB (or Update the whole Android Studio, maybe).

Comment: Still not working even after updating.

Answer (score 0):

You've put all of this into a `FrameLayout` with large fixed margins. Your missing views are likely offscreen (`android:layout_marginTop="625sp"` means that you're offsetting it by quite a lot; also, you should use `dp`).  The reason it works in the preview is likely because you're previewing what it would look like on a larger screen.

I'm assuming you did this because otherwise FrameLayout just puts all the views on top of each other.  You could solve this by building your UI using [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), or some combination of `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`.  Position the views relative to each other and the screen, not at large fixed offsets.